# Google app engine error, don't know where to start looking

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm receiving this error when I attempt to start an app using google app engine :

```
Loading modules
   com.bookmark.Mobile_bookmark
      [ERROR] Unable to find 'com/bookmark/Mobile_bookmark.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
[ERROR] shell failed in doStartup method
```

I don't have a file called `Mobile_bookmark.gwt.xml`. My project name is mobile-bookmark

Why is this error occuring ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's looking for Mobile_bookmark.gwt.xml (the wrong file), I'd check how you are starting the server.

For example, under Eclipse, I'd check run configurations --> arguments to see if "Mobile_bookmark" got into there.  (you can get to run configurations by selecting the little triangle next to either the green debug or run button you use to start it --- or RUN (menu in eclipse) -- run configurations -- select your project)

Change the file name to whatever *.gwt.xml file you do have.  I suspect it's mobile-bookmark.gwt.xml.

Look under /src/yourpath/yourproject/

Your layout is probably like:

```
/src/yourpath/yourproject/*.gwt.xml
/src/yourpath/yourproject/client
/src/yourpath/yourproject/server
```

Comment: When I remove teh argument I am now receiving error : Missing required argument 'module[s]'
Google Web Toolkit 2.4.0

Comment: don't remove it.  change it to mobile-bookmark.gwt.xml (I assume that is the file you have.  You need some *.gwt.xml file for sure.)